# How to change pageable messages of kendo grid in razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I found in javascript but i could't manage to do it.
Can anyone say how "display" will be in razor?

```
pageable: {
    messages: {
        display: "{0} - {1} of {2} items", //{0} is the index of the first record on the page, {1} - index of the last record on the page, {2} is the total amount of records
        empty: "No items to display",
        page: "Page",
        of: "of {0}", //{0} is total amount of pages
        itemsPerPage: "items per page",
        first: "Go to the first page",
        previous: "Go to the previous page",
        next: "Go to the next page",
        last: "Go to the last page",
        refresh: "Refresh"
    }
}
```

**Razor view**

```
.Pageable(??)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#messages).

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("grid")
        .Pageable(pager => pager
            .Messages(messages => messages.Display("Showing items from {0} to {1}. Total items: {2}"))
        )
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax() // or Server()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home"))
        )
     )
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to build up a little more on the previous answer.

```
.Messages(message => message.ItemsPerPage("ItemsPerPage"))
                    .Messages(message => message.Page("Page"))
                    .Messages(message => message.Of("Of"))
                    .Messages(message => message.Display("Display"))
                    .Messages(message => message.Empty("Empty"))
                    .Messages(message => message.First("First"))
                    .Messages(message => message.Last("Last"))
                    .Messages(message => message.Next("Next"))
                    .Messages(message => message.Previous("Previous"))
                    .Messages(message => message.Refresh("Refresh"))
```