# Change kendo grid text labels

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've got a kendo grid:

```
<div id="datagrid">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("datagrid_Concessoes")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Width(70);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Code);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
            columns.Bound(c => c.CreationDate);
            columns.Bound(c => c.CreationUser);
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 534px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Selectable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(15)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetConcessoes", "MasterData"))
        )
    )
</div>
```

And it looks like this:

[image: print]

I want to change the text that shows by default within the red lines.
How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change pageable messages of kendo grid in razor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685860/how-to-change-pageable-messages-of-kendo-grid-in-razor)